# Object format resulting from a angularfire query

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

Why does the result of a firebase query come like this?

[image]

[image]

What is this "e"?
And this $$ conf, $ priority, $ resolved should appear even or am I doing it using the query in the wrong way?

Controller:

```
Parking.getParking(id).then(function(result) {
   console.log(result);
})
```

Service:

```
getParking: function(id) {
    var refParkingById =  firebase.database().ref('parking').child(id);
    return $firebaseObject(refParkingById).$loaded();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually If you use angular fire, it adds these `$` prefixed keys automatically.

Here is doc https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-arrays.html#section-meta-fields